Primeng calendar - setting width without scrollbars
I'm using the primeng calendar component in an angular app. I have it inline and showing 2 months side-by-side. When I try to set a width for it, anything less than around 800px simply brings up the horizontal scroll bars. How do I properly configure it so that it respects the width I'm trying to set?
In poking around with devtools, it seems that '.p-datepicker-group-container' is possibly the point where width is fixed. But I can't see anything like 'min-width' being used anywhere.


Can you please share the code in StackBlitz and provide more details to let us know about the issue?
